# QGIS WFS layer is not valid

Tags: qgis, wfs, error

I am pretty new in working with WFS services and need some help to understand the basics.

This is the URL of the WFS I want to work with:
https://haleconnect.com/ows/services/org.732.341f2791-919e-49de-8d86-3b18e040c430_wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0

When I connect it there is no problem, but when I want to add any of the listed layers I get an error message saying: Layer is not valid: The layer pagingEnabled='true' preferCoordinatesForWfsT11='false' srsname='EPSG:4326' typename='tn-a:AerodromeNode' url='https://haleconnect.com/ows/services/org.732.341f2791-919e-49de-8d86-3b18e040c430_wfs' version='auto' is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Have you talked to the provider?

Comment: does it work in a browser or with curl on the command line?

Comment: Do use INSPIRE WFS services for learning WFS. The INSPIRE datasets are all so called "complex features" and QGIS can only handle "simple features".  Simple feature means "each row has one geometry and a fixed set of attributes". Complex features can be much more structural. See the INSPIRE data specification about traffic networks, page 5/70, from https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_TN_v3.0.pdf. QGIS and GDAL can sometimes find some geometries and attributes if the GML from the WFS service is first saved on disk.

Answer (score 3):

Able to retrieve the content and then read it then in QGIS e.g

```
wget -O /tmp/aerodromenode.gml "https://haleconnect.com/ows/services/org.732.341f2791-919e-49de-8d86-3b18e040c430_wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=tn-a:AerodromeNode"
```

and open the gml in QGIS "well".

Not sure about the error but could be related to `tn-a:AerodromeNode` typename that use Inspire namespace (PS: an hypothesis, no hard fact to confirm). Issue seems to be about consuming WFS layer from QGIS or "normal" WFS syntax in QGIS vector layer

Work also with ogr2ogr e.g

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG hale_connect_content.gpkg WFS:"https://haleconnect.com/ows/services/org.732.341f2791-919e-49de-8d86-3b18e040c430_wfs" tn-a:AerodromeNode -nln aerodromenode
```